# RmarkDown iterative loop

Tags: r, loops, knitr, r-markdown

I have an RMarkdown file that produce a report for a business unit "Ux". I want to make an iterative loop to produce a specific report for all the business unit "U1, U2, U3,..." of the business.

in the Rmarkdown file I have this input :

````
```{r , warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, autodep=TRUE,cache.vars='pole' } 
pole <- "21" 
```
````

where pole is the business unit identification variable.

then i have a R script call that do some stuff with pole variable.

````
```{r LOAD, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, autodep=TRUE, cache=FALSE }
require(knitr)
source('POLE2.r', local=environment())
```
````

How can i produce every single report (an html file for each unit) for pole <- [1,2,3,4,5...] with an iterative loop ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with parametrized reports:

Add the following to the YAML-preamble:

```
---
params:
  pole: 21 # default value
---
```

In your code change `pole <- "21"` to `pole <- params$pole`

Then run a loop like:

```
poles <- 1:5 # define your set
for (pole in poles)
  rmarkdown::render(input = "yourFile.Rmd", 
      output_file = paste0("yourOutput_", pole, ".html"),
      params = list(pole = pole)
  )
```

See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I loop through a list op values and produce reports for every entry. Because my company has an older version of R and Rmarkdown, I cannot run parameterized reports.

```
for(i in seq_along(business))
{
  B <- business[i]
  knit2html("Report.Rmd"
            ,paste0(filepath,"/business ",B ,".html")
  )
}
```

`B` is available for the `Report.Rmd` script to use.